# Can't pass input values using state from formik to post api

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api, formik

```
<Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={{
          name: profileItems[0].value,   //these values coming from api
          phoneNo: profileItems[1].value,
          email: profileItems[2].value,
          address: profileItems[3].value,
        }}
        validationSchema={profileSchema}
        validator={() => ({})}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
           formData.append("name", values.name);
           formData.append("phoneNo", values.phoneNo);
           formData.append("email", values.email);
           formData.append("address", values.address);

           // using state variable

           // const currentItems = [...profileItems];

           // currentItems[0]["value"] = values.name;
           // currentItems[1]["value"] = values.phoneNo;

           // setProfileItems(currentItems);

           postCustomer(formData);
        }}
      >
 {(props) => (
          <>
            <View>

              {/* ========== NAME ========== */}

              <TextInput
                title={profileItems[0].title}
                defaultValue={profileItems[0].value}
                name="name"
                onBlur={props.handleBlur("name")}
                onChangeText={props.handleChange("name")}
                value={props.values.name}
              />
              <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                {props.touched.name && props.errors.name}
              </Text>

              {/* ========== NUMBER ========== */}

              <TextInput
                title={profileItems[1].title}
                defaultValue={profileItems[1].value}
                name="phoneNo"
                onBlur={props.handleBlur("phoneNo")}
                onChangeText={props.handleChange("phoneNo")}
                value={props.values.phoneNo}
              />
              <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                {props.touched.name && props.errors.name}
              </Text>

              <AppButton
                title="Save"
                style={styles.button}
                titleStyle={styles.textBtn}
                onPress={props.handleSubmit}
              />
           </>
         )}
      </Formik>
```

Api is receiving the values by **key**. So, if I store all the captured values in formData as key, value pair. **I can receive these values in fetch api but when I use state variable to send values to fetch api, I can't able to receive them. I want to send values using state same like formData.** Because I wanted to appear the values entered by user on run-time. Basically I want the change to appear in same inputs from which the user have sent the values. Wonder where I'm doing wrong.

```
const postCustomer = (formData) => {
fetch(`${apiUrl.baseURL}post_customer.php`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
  body: formData, // This is working but for this values are not appearing on run-time.
  //body: profileItems,   This is not working.
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  });
```

};

Comment: Why can't just `postCustomer(values)` ?

Comment: Tried that nothing happens.

Comment: what you mean by state variables ?

Comment: I think `profileItems` is not `FormData` object.

Comment: @Shyam const [profileItems, setProfileItems] = useState();

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim Yes it's not a formData object. Instead of formData i want to use state just like formData. Is it possible?

Comment: an additional state is not needed when Formik handles the state for you .

Comment: @CopyPaste how you want to send data to post request depends on your backend api implementation. How are you receiving the post request body in backend?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** Web developer didn't set response in the api. So I was not getting the data. After sending the response back, I'm able to get the data which the user submitted through form.

**Problem 2:**
Now that I got the response back. I used the state. In my case

```
const [profileItems, setProfileItems] = useState([]);
```

I made the copy of *profileItems* in *currentProfileItems*. After setting the corresponding values through json. I manage to change the state on run-time.

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl.baseURL}get_customer.php`);
  const json = await response.json();
  if (json.error === true) {
    console.log(json.error_msg);
  } else {
    setProfileImage(json.image);

    //make copy of original array
    let currentProfileItems = [...profileItems];

    // performing operations on copyied array
    currentProfileItems[0].value = json.name;
    currentProfileItems[1].value = json.phoneNo;
    currentProfileItems[2].value = json.email;
    currentProfileItems[3].value = json.address;

    // setting the new state
    setProfileItems(currentProfileItems);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```